# Knockout store element reference for later use

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This is probably super simplistic and I'm probably just missing it but...

I want to save off a reference back in my `ViewModel` to an element, so that I can manipulate that element from a completely different function later.

---

**To make a short story long,** I have a simple list created with a `foreach` loop inside an observable array. All works very magically.

I later push items to the observed array with a click action on a button or something. Also works very magically.

Now somewhere down the line from that click, an ajax call gets fired off using jQuery and I want to manipulate something about that added element itself in the callback, in this case remove a class. This class was added using the `foreach`'s built-in `afterAdd` callback.

So basically:

```
1 Button is clicked
2 record pushed to observed array
3 foreach automagically adds new line item to the dom and adds a class to it
4 ajax call is made to something
5 success callback for ajax needs to remove the class
```

I have the index of the added array item, so in theory if I have the reference to the element creating the list, I can grab a child element by that index and have my way with it.

---

Is this a thing that can be done or am I way over-complicating it?

Comment: It looks doable. Do you have code for the first 4 steps?

Comment: Why not just track the state of ajax request for every item in the list? Just add an observable property (e.g. `.loading`) to each new item before adding it to the list, and bind class of corresponding element against that property. Since request is finished set the property to false to remove a class automagically.

Comment: If I understood correctly, all you need to do is pass in the `$element` binding context from the HTML into a prototype bound function (see [the docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) for more detail...)

Comment: 1. Add an observable property to the record with value `true`, 2. Use the `css` binding and the property to add a class to the elements inside `foreach`, 5. Lookup the record (by index?) and set the observable property to `false`. Knockout will remove the class for you. (Note: there was an answer showing this approach but it unfortunately got deleted)